# What does "never a break" mean?

Tags: meaning

I was watching the movie "As good as it gets" and came across the phrase "never a break" in reference to a car.  What does it mean?

Also, what does the movie title itself mean?

edit: replaced brake with break.

Comment: why downvotes ? Should I already know it ?

Comment: I've voted to close as "too localised" because your misinterpretation of *brake* for *break* there isn't likely to happen to many other people. Besides, Googling quoted *"never a break"* and *"never a brake"* gives 100 times more hits for the first version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was probably *"never a [break](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/break)"* meaning "never any time to rest":

> **break**
>
> **78**. a brief rest, as from work: *The actors took a ten-minute break from rehearsal.*

This would mean that the speaker is saying he never gets time to rest (or time for himself).

"As good as it gets" means *the best it will ever become*.

Answer (score 1):

Without having seen the movie, I'm going to assume that the character actually said "Never a break", which is a shorter form of "I never get a break", which means either "I don't get to take any breaks [rest periods]" or "Whenever something happens to me, it always happens in a way that makes things more difficult for me."  (If I did "get a break", it would mean that something happened in a way that made things easier or better for me.)